# An Inequality in Linear Algebra (Stuck in the Proof)

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question was on an exam which I didn't manage to solve. Later, I saw that the same question appears in page 146 of Kostrikin and Manin book:

Suppose that $f:V\to V$ is an operator in a unitary space and that for any $v\in V$ there exist some $k>0$ such that $|f(v),v|\leq k|v|^2$. Prove that for all $v,w \in V$$$|(f(v),w)|+|(v,f(w))|\leq 2k|v||w|.$$

---

I tried using the fact that $V$ is unitary space so that the inner product $(.,.)$ is positive definite and Hermitian but I couldn't go much further. I think there must be a way to get cancellation in $k|v+w|^2$ so that only $2k|v||w|$ remains. Any hint or a solution is appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my answer to solve the problem correctly this time. I had underestimated the problem earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x,y \in V$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Substitute now $v = x + ty$ in the condition $|(f(v),v)| \geq 0 $ which is always true, one then uses the triangle inequality:

$$
0 \leq |(fx,x) + t^2 (fy,y) + t(fx,y) + t(fy,x)| \leq |(fx,x)| + t^2 |(fy,y)| + t \mbox{ sgn}(t) [|(fx,y)| + |(fy,x)|] 
$$
For this to be true it is necessary that the quadratic equation above have no real roots on $t$ (or has at most one), hence the discriminant of the equation must be negative or zero, taking into account both cases when $t \geq0$ and $t\leq0$ gives the same condition, that is:

$$[|(fx,y)|+ |(fy,x)|]^2 \leq 4 |(fx,x)||(fy,y)| \leq 4 k^2 |x|^2|y|^2 $$

From whence it follows that:

$$ |(fx,y)| + |(x,fy)| \leq 2k |x| |y|$$

Comment: I'm not sure how that works because I've tried that before. Your suggestion gives $|(f(x+y),x+y)|\leq |f(x+y)||x+y|$ but what happens afterwards?

Comment: I don't think anyone could follow your hint. Otherwise they (including myself) would have upvoted your answer. Could you elaborate on your proof a little more?

Comment: Sorry, I just realise that the way I was thinking is not correct. I will see whether I can find a correct answer.

Comment: Wow! This looks solid. Thanks for taking your time and thinking about this problem. One question: why in the RHS of inequality we have $t[|(fx,y)| + |(fy,x)|]$? I mean why is $t$ outside of the absolute value. What if $t<0$? I would appreciate if you explain  a little bit the line after the inequality.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the observation! I have made a correction, it should be $|t| = t$ sgn$(t)$ instead of just $t$, so one has to look at both cases $t\geq 0$ and $t \leq 0$ which nevertheless give rise to the same condition. It should be ok now. This was a subtle problem! I think it is rather tough for an exam.